# How to kill Elixir Daemon

Tags: elixir

I start daemon of elixir.

```
elixir --detached -S mix run
```

But I cannot find way to kill this.

(My Server is CentOS.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Find the process ID using `ps -eaf|grep elixir` and kill the process using `kill <process_id>`

Comment: If it doesn't die, then do a `kill -9 <process_id>`

Comment: this works: 
sudo fuser -k 4001/tcp
if its on port 4001

Answer (score 1):

As @Werner typed in comment for me it worked:

`sudo fuser -k 4001/tcp`

Change `4001` to your port